# About MS Outlook 2013 Repeated Password Prompt

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, troubleshooting

So, the situation goes like this.

Previously my email was configured using POP on Hostgrator email server. But I wanted to switch to G Suite. So, I transferred my personal email to G Suite, added new account in Outlook, and removed the old account after taking the Outlook Data File as backup.

Since I need old emails so I have attached OST file(the one I took as backup) as local fodler in Outlook to access old emails but the problem is that it is keep asking for the old Hostgator's server password. The hostgator email server doesn't exist anymore...what should I do to get rid of that password prompt ?

I am using Outlook 2013.

Comment: Do you mean PST file? OST files are not used by POP3 accounts that I know of, and you can’t “attach” them as a local folder. PST Files open easily and would not prompt for credentials. So, please describe step by step what you have done if you want help.

Comment: Agree with the comment above, POP account use PST file to save data. Regarding credential prompting issue, you can also check this ForumFAQ in TechNet forum: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bcd2d9c2-1a1b-4446-bf32-69fee8cdf11b/why-does-outlook-keep-prompting-for-password?forum=outlook